# Will wix upgrade invoke old version msi to uninstall?

Tags: wix, upgrade

I am stuck in preserving registries from old version msi on upgrade. Because the old version msi do not grant read permission to admin, I can't use RegistrySearch to get my work done.

Instead, in the wix script Product.wxs, I use NeverOverWrite="yes" and Permanent="yes" in Component element to keep all registries even on uninstall.

What confuses me now is that the registries get lost when the new version msi upgrades the old one. Note the new version msi is generated by the new Product.wxs, which set NeverOverWrite="yes" and Permanent="yes" in component element.

I guess the reason is that on upgrade, "msiexec" will invoke old version msi to uninstall the app, during which registries is removed. The modification to Product.wxs will not take effect until next relase upgrades current one. I do not confirm my guess because I can't find any reference on Google to support this idea. Could any one to clarify this problm to me?